# Can't restart Ubuntu, only shutdown and manually start again

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics, 23.10

I hope you can help me with my problem.

I am currently using Ubuntu 23.10 on my Computer.

My specs are as following:

- Ryzen 5 7500F
- 32 GB of Corsair 6000 MhZ RAM
- AMD Radeon RX 7800 XT
- 2 TB of M.2 PCIe 4.0 Storage
- Mainbaord: Gigabyte A620M DS3H

My Ubuntu is configured as following:

- Updated Mesa Drivers using ppa oibaf/graphics-drivers (also tested without)
- 6.7.2 liquorix "gaming kernel" (also tested with default kernel)
- Default Ubuntu gnome desktop on wayland
- All packages updated

I had to upgrade the drivers + kernel because of [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/3092) driver issue, but as I said, the problem I am having is also occurring with the default drivers and kernel.

So now to my problem: I can't restart my computer to Ubuntu using the "Reboot"-Button in gnome, using "reboot"-Command or any other means. I can't even reboot from Windows to Ubuntu or even a Live-USB linux instance. It just shows the grub menu but after that the screens stay black. I can boot into windows after a restart without an issue and I can reboot into Linux Mint 21.2 after restart without an issue. This only affects Ubuntu 23.10 and is happening since I installed it. I always have to fully power off my system and restart it using the power button.

Has anyone experienced the same issue or has an idea on how to fix it? Its not that bad but at least quite annoying. I'm not that experienced so if you need any logs or something just tell me.

I`ve just updated the BIOS but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you type **sudo shutdown -r now** ?

Comment: Well it restarts like usual, I see the "gigabyte" bootscreen with the options to go to bios, I see the GRUB menu, where I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows but after choosing Ubuntu I wont get a signal on any screen. Its exactly the same when powering it up, except then ubuntu boots normally.

Answer (score 0):

AMD GPU support includes Ubuntu 22.04.4 for RX 7000 series cards, and these drivers appear to be more stable than the kernel drivers. I know from experience that Mesa with ppa oibaf/graphics-drivers are problematic and I recommend ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa if it is available for Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: [Register kernel-mode driver](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/ubuntu.html)

Comment: Hi, tanks for the ideas. kisak/kisak-mesa didn't help either - it was actually worse since my driver related crashes came back. So now I'm back on oibaf. AMDGPU is not an option since many games (like Halo) doesn't work with it. Actually I'm pretty happy with my current config. It runs super smooth and super stable. The only problem that is persisting is that I can't restart. Maybe that will be fixed in the future...